# What is the term for number of nodes from root to the leaf in Binary tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

The depth of a node is the number of edges from the root to the node. What is the term for number of nodes from root to a node including root and node ? Eg: A with right child B with a right child C. Such  tree has height of 2, but `some term` of 3.

Comment: Isn't it always depth plus one?

Comment: true, but to give more reference, I wanted to name a function that computes this `depth+1`, just curious if it had any official term ?

Comment: Name it `depth`, and return the value minus one :):):)

Comment: 3 generations sounds just right, as @jilles de wit answered.

Comment: What is the context in which you need this separate word for `depth + 1`?

Comment: @G.Bach true, `context` is, I wanted to `name` a function that computes this depth+1, just curious if it had any official term ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is an official term for this. But because nodes in a binary tree below the root node are often called child nodes I'd suggest: generation. So in your example the tree has 3 `generations`.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of the example you gave (A with right child B with a right child C) would actually have a height of 3 (since root node height =  1; right child B height = 2; right child C height = 3).

I believe the term you are looking for is the **depth**. Again, in the example you gave, right child B depth = 1 and its right child C depth = 2.

```
Height: 1      A                Depth: 0
                \
                 \
Height: 2         B             Depth: 1
                   \
                    \
Height: 3            C          Depth: 2
```

Also, C is considered to be a **descendant** of B, and B is an **ancestor** of C.

Answer (score -1):

It's simply the size of the (sub)tree whose root is A.

**edited**

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28data_structure%29):

"A subtree of a tree T is a tree consisting of a node in T and all of its descendants in T.[c][1] Nodes thus correspond to subtrees (each node corresponds to the subtree of itself and all its descendants) – the subtree corresponding to the root node is the entire tree, and each node is the root node of the subtree it determines; the subtree corresponding to any other node is called a proper subtree (in analogy to the term proper subset)."

Comment: The poster is asking for a term for the number of nodes you visit going from root to leaf (or back). That has nothing to do with number of nodes in any subtree. Unless you're using a definition of size completely different from the standard, this still answers the wrong question.